# How can I pass arguments dynamically to a DataFrame.apply() lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to run the Pandas `apply()` method for a Dataframe to create a new column, as follows:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(groupby).apply(lambda x: some_function(x, df['existing_column']))
```

So, basically, I'm trying to pass the second argument of `some_function` dynamically, relative to what `df['existing_column']` stores as a value for each row (values differ).

The error I get is the common `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`. Is there a proper way to to this? I tried doing a for-loop for each row, but that kills my CPU.

Comment: Can you explain more? what are parameters? Is possible create some data sample with sample function?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if need new column by `existing_column` per groups:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('col')['existing_column'].transform(lambda x: funct(x, par))
```